# How to Fix 'java.lang.ClassCastException: org.redisson.RedissonReference cannot be cast to org.redisson.api.RLock'

Tags: java, concurrency, redisson

I am using RMap to store RLock. When I am trying to get(key) from this map, it is returning me an instance of RedissonReference instead of RLock.
I am not able to cast it to RLock. I am using the below code:

```java
RMap<String,RLock> locks = redissonClient.getMap("locksMap");
RLock existingLock = locks.get(name);
```

I'm getting the below exception here:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.redisson.RedissonReference cannot be cast to org.redisson.api.RLock
```

Answer (score 0):

`RLock` can't be stored in Map as value, since it doesn't extend `RObject` interface. Use name with prefix for `RLock` object instead